# Outer class containing inner class - instantiate the inner class as a member of the outer class

Tags: c++, inner-classes

Currently I am trying to get the following code to compile:

terminallog.hh

```
#ifndef TERMINALLOG_HH
#define TERMINALLOG_HH

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Terminallog {
public:

    Terminallog();
    virtual ~Terminallog();    

    class Warn {
    public:
        Warn();

    private:
        bool lineended;  
    };
    friend class Terminallog::Warn;

protected:

private:
    Warn warn;     

};
```

terminallog.cc

```
 // stripped code

 Terminallog::Terminallog() {
     Warn this->warn();
 }

Terminallog::Warn::Warn() {
    this->lineended = true;
}

//stripped code
```

Well, as you probably guessed alredy, its failing ;-). My compiler is saying:

```
g++ src/terminallog.cc inc/terminallog.hh -o test -Wall -Werror 
In file included from src/terminallog.cc:8:
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:56: error: declaration of ‘Terminallog::Warn Terminallog::warn’
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:24: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘void Terminallog::warn(std::string)’
```

which leaves me out of options. I am obviously doing something wrong, however I have no idea of how to resolve this. I would appreciate any hints.

Thanks in advance

ftiaronsem

Comment: Read your error message - you're not posting the right code - you have a `Warn warn` member variable and a `void warn(std::string)` member function, rename one of them

Comment: @Erik. Uups, perfectly correct, and pretty impressive ;-). There is a bit more code in this class, which I stripped. Thanks very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Warn this->warn();` is not valid C++ syntax - if you want to initialize the `warn` member, use an initialization list (you don't need to in this case - the default constructor is called implicitly!).

```
Terminallog::Terminallog() : warn()
{
   // other constructor code
}


// note that `Warn::Warn()` is invoked implicitly on `wake`, so 

TerminalLog::Terminallog() {}

// would be equivalent
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. That is very interesting. How can I access a method of the inner class from another c++ file? I planed doing something like this: Terminallog tlog(); tlog.Warn.PubMethod(); from other cpp files. Thanks in advance

Comment: lol, you already wrote that in your answer. I just read a tutorial about initialization lists and then I noticed. Thank you very much. You really deserve to reach the 10k points soon ;-)